# image not found in Image.Network

Tags: image, http, flutter

in my app i have ListTile where i show my images but how can i change my images url if i have 404 error, on default image, cuz if i get 404 i have white screen in image, i trying this:

```
                String imageURL = 'someURL';
                String imageUrlDef = 'defaulURL';
                String url = imageUrlDef;

                Future checkImg() async{
                  var response = await http.get(imageURL);

                  if(response.statusCode == 200){
                    url = imageURL;
                  }
                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use  [CachedNetworkImage](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image)  library for the check Image availability on the server or not ,if there is image not available on server then ,it redirect  you to the `errorWidget` where you can create your Error widget as you want , below is the example of it, please check it once

```
 CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: "https://picsum.photos/250?image=9",
      placeholder: (context, url) => new CircularProgressIndicator(),
      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),  //// YOU CAN CREATE YOUR OWN ERROR WIDGET HERE
                   )
```

Comment: Happy to help you man!! Keep happy coding :)  And thank you very much for your lovely words :)

Answer (score -1):

Try to open the Image in a new Tab, because Flutter may not recognise the Image in the Website.